# Use dodge with geom_point and error bar to horizontally display coefficients from models

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have the following data-set

```
                                 term  estimate std.error statistic      p.value   conf.low conf.high  df                outcome model
                    outgroup_pairing1  9.173850  2.336151  3.926908 0.0001574491   4.539555 13.808145 101 outgroup_feelings_diff     1
                    outgroup_pairing1 11.663866  3.330378  3.502265 0.0006886152   5.057292 18.270440 101 outgroup_feelings_diff     2
 politicsRepublican:outgroup_pairing1 -5.002525  4.645316 -1.076897 0.2840919026 -14.217582  4.212531 101 outgroup_feelings_diff     2
                    outgroup_pairing1 10.657113  3.575874  2.980282 0.0036079930   3.563540 17.750686 101 outgroup_feelings_diff     3
 politicsRepublican:outgroup_pairing1 -4.928449  4.647266 -1.060505 0.2914443020 -14.147374  4.290476 101 outgroup_feelings_diff     3
                    outgroup_pairing1 10.512772  4.162351  2.525681 0.0131016794   2.255788 18.769757 101 outgroup_feelings_diff     4
 politicsRepublican:outgroup_pairing1 -5.359123  4.978743 -1.076401 0.2843123953 -15.235609  4.517363 101 outgroup_feelings_diff     4
```

I want to be able to output the main effect and the interaction coefficients and their attendant error bars, grouped by the model number.  Here is my best attempt:

```
ggplot(aes(x = estimate, y = model, color = term, group= term)) + 
geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 2) + 
geom_point(position="dodge") + 
geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high, height = 0.1),position="dodge") + 
ggtitle("Change in Outgroup Warmth") + 
geom_text(aes(label = paste("β = ", round(estimate, 2), "; p = ", round(p.value, 5)), vjust = -.5)) +
theme_bw() +  
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
ylab("Model")  +
xlab("Estimate")
```

But this yields the following.

[image]

I want the coefficients horizontally "dodged" so they don't overlap like that.  I'd also like the "a" in the legend to be removed.

Answer (score 4):

You can't in the current direction, dodging only works in the x direction. But you can use `coord_flip` and define everything the other way around:

```
pos <- position_dodge(width = 0.5)
ggplot(df, aes(y = estimate, x = model, color = term, group= term)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 2) + 
  geom_point(position = pos) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high, width = 0.1), position = pos) + 
  ggtitle("Change in Outgroup Warmth") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("β = ", round(estimate, 2), "; p = ", round(p.value, 5)), vjust = -.5),
            position = pos, show.legend = FALSE) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +  
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  ylab("Model")  +
  xlab("Estimate")
```

[image]

Also note the `show.legend = FALSE` in your `geom_text` to not have the text show in your legend (the "a").

Answer (score 2):

Your question has been well answered by @Axeman.  Alternatively, if you would like to keep your original code structure, you could just change your variable `model`. In the following code, I added one line `mutate(model = ifelse(term == "outgroup_pairing1", model - 0.1, model +0.1)) %>%` to your original code. `position="dodge"` may not be necessary, removed. Also, I used `nudge_y = 0.1` to adjust the text position although it is not part of your OP question. Personally, I feel `nudge_y` is more intuitive than `vjust` for this purpose.

```
library(tidyverse) 
df %>% 
  mutate(model = ifelse(term == "outgroup_pairing1", model - 0.1, model +0.1)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = estimate, y = model, color = term, group= term)) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 2) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high, height = 0.03)) + 
  ggtitle("Change in Outgroup Warmth") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("β = ", round(estimate, 2), "; p = ", 
                              round(p.value, 5))), nudge_y = 0.1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_bw() +  
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  ylab("Model")  +
  xlab("Estimate")
```

[image]

Comment: Ah!  This is very clever.  Hadn't thought about this.  Thanks for the tip on `nudge_y` as well.  Wasn't aware of that